# Does STM32F103 supports floating point under KEIL IDE

Tags: arm, cortex-m, keil, fpu

I'm working on an embedded C project, on Keil IDE; using stm32F103RB microcontroller
I need to use floating point values %f, but it doesn't work, my serial monitor doesn't print any float,  but works fine with integers.

Is there any method to activate FPU ARM M3 microcontrollers with Keil?

Comment: I dont think the cortex-m3 has an fpu, you can use soft float.

Comment: thank you for response,  how should i use soft float ?

Comment: what does the keil documentation say about it?

Comment: The "%f" in your question makes me think this is not about hard or soft floats at all, but about printf - am I right?  If so it's very common in embedded environments for the default implementation of printf to not support floating point output, because it makes compiled binaries very much smaller.  You don't say what libraries you're linking against though.

Comment: i have integrated printf-stdarg.c library which allow to use printf function , it supports %c and %d but not floating points %f, i'm looking for another alternative ! maybe shoud i reimplement this printf library ?